# Puzzling set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let's have the following numbers $23, 40, 42, 44, \sqrt{43},\ 128i, 130, \sqrt{172}\  $. What is the relationship between these numbers, taken four at a time?

There are only two combinations when you take four of these numbers at a time, from which you obtain $(ab)^2 \pm c^2= k^n $. The puzzle is to find these two combinations.

Comment: could you plese explain what you mean by "taken four at a time". Does it mean I choose any four numbers and there is a relationship or do I have to find four numbers bing in relationship...

Comment: @ThomasL. Yes, the puzzle is to find which four of these numbers are related and how they relate.

Comment: This is still a very open question. 
I can choose numbers $40, 42, 44, \sqrt{43}$ as they all contain a 4
or I choose $40, 42, 44, 130$ because those are all even integers...
Do the remaining 4 numbers play a role or are those totally irrelevant?

Comment: @ThomasL. All numbers are relevant and have to be used in order to arrive at the answer.

Comment: Your description is still pretty ambiguous to me. Could elaborate on what exactly you mean by "taken four at a time", or would you say this puzzle fits the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag?

Comment: @Magma this is not an enigmatic puzzle.You are allowed to use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, brackets, exponents  in a such a way as to find the relationships of four numbers at a time. These groups of four numbers have the same relationship.

Comment: Do we have to look at all $70$ possibilities to take four numbers? Or is it only four consecutive numbers?

Comment: @Αlain Remillard. They are not consecutive.

Comment: Can you please add those additional instructions into the question itself, and perhaps also a simple example showing what would be a correct solution (with other numbers). By *exponents* do you mean the power has to be one of the numbers, for example $23^{40}$ ?

Comment: @Weather Vane. I am going to give half of the solution. These numbers taken four at a time formulate Diofantine equations.

Comment: You could give an abstract example to keep it simple, for example `a + b + g + h = c - d - e - f` (assuming that is what you mean - nobody knows what you are asking).

Comment: @Weather Vane An  examble is like this ab^2+/-c^2=k^n

Comment: As I asked earlier, the **question** needs improving with an [edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/93686/edit) - not a slow drip-feed of information in comments. The question is very near to being closed. Your example in the last comment used five symbols - what happens to the other three? And where does the exponent $2$ come from, it's not in the list?

Comment: I edited the question, Now it should be easily understood by all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the minuses, this was a really nice puzzle. Here is the first set

> $(23 \times \sqrt{172})^2-130^2 = 42^3$

Here is the second set

> $(40 \times \sqrt{43})^2-(128i)^2 = 44^3$

Comment: @Dimitry Kamenetsky. I am delighted you can see the substance of the puzzle. As for the negative votes, I have no choice but  to endure them.

Comment: Don't worry about the votes. This was a great puzzle! In the future just try to write the full set of instructions so it is crystal clear what you are asking from us.